# SAS formatting datalines

Tags: sas, format

Ok my last question I am having a hard time formatting this

```
data practice;
input
Datalines;
employee_id   Name gender   years   dept     salary    Birthday

         1 Mitchell, Jane A  f    6     shoe     22,450  12/30/1960
         2 Miller, Frances T  f  8  appliance      .     11/27/1965
         3 Evans, Richard A  m   9  appliance    42,900  02/15/1973
         4 Fair, Suzanne K  f    3  clothing     29,700  03/09/1958
         5 Meyers, Thomas D  m  5  appliance     33,700  10/22/1961
         6 Rogers, Steven F  m  3    shoe         27,000  09/12/1960
         7 Anderson, Frank F  m  5  clothing      33,000  03/09/1958
        10 Baxter, David T  m  2     shoe         23,900  11/25/1966
        11 Wood, Brenda L  f  3     clothing      33,000  01/14/1962
        12 Wheeler, Vickie M  f  7  appliance     31,500  12/23/1975
        13 Hancock, Sharon T  f  1  clothing      21,000  01/17/1972
        14 Looney, Roger M    m  10 appliance     31,500  06/09/1973
        15 Fry, Marie E     f    6  clothing      29,700  05/25/1967
; 
run;quit;
Proc print data=practice;
run;quit;
```

Ok my question is there a way to do this without having to count each individual space? Even when I do count the data still does not properly print out what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance this should be my last question afterwards I should be ready for this final.

Comment: Your input statement goes before datalines. And you need to specify which are character with $.

Comment: My bad I don't actually have access to SAS atm because of...school program issues. Anyway my input was before my datalines originally however for some reason when I put $. after each of my input variables it still does not format them properly. Can I do this without counting or no matter what do I have to use counting?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't assign a character length, SAS will use the length of the first value it encounters and assign it to all the values in that column. You can use the statement `length var $w;` before your data lines statement to set your own length. Using the option `dsd` tells SAS to use comma as your variable delimiter, read strings enclosed in quotation marks as a single variable, and to strip them off before saving the variable. If using blank spaces as your delimiter, make sure there are no blank spaces in front of each row below the dataline statement.

```
data practice;
infiles datalines dsd;
length Name $50. dept $9.;
input employee_id   Name $ gender $  years   dept $     salary $   Birthday MMDDYY10.;
format Birthday MMDDYY10.;
Datalines;
1, "Mitchell, Jane A", f,   6,     shoe,     "22,450",  12/30/1960
2, "Miller, Frances T",  f,  8, appliance,     ,  11/27/1965
; 
run;
Proc print data=practice;
run;quit;
```